# Como obter e enviar para um ficheiro php uma seleção de combobox

Tags: php, html, post

Necessito saber como chegar ao valor selecionado na *combobox* quando se  carrega no botão de submeter e como chamar esse valor no novo ficheiro `.php`:

Sei que já existem exemplos parecidos por aqui, mas atenção que a minha combobox é dinamica não fixa, e atenção tambem que tenho `.html`, depois `.php`e novamente `.html`, isso está me a fazer confusão.

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<?php
require_once('auth.php');
require_once('config.php');
require_once('no-cache-headers.php');
require_once('functions.php');
?>

<title>Nova Mensagem</title>
<link href="Formatacao.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Bem-vindo <?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME'];?></h1>

<form id="regForm" name="regForm" method="post" action="verificarMensagem.php">
  <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">

<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','comunicat','comunicat');

mysql_select_db('Comunicat');

$iduser =$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'];

$query="Select * from Usuarios where id <> '$iduser'";

$_SESSION['IdUser'] = $iduser;

$resultado=mysql_query($query);
echo '<select name=”Nome”>';

while($linha=mysql_fetch_array($resultado))
{

echo '<option value="' . $linha['ID'] . '">' . $linha['Nome'] . '</option>';

}

echo '</select>';

?>

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="mensagem" id="mensagem">
    </textarea>

      <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

------------ verificarMensagem.php -----------------

```
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "comunicat", "comunicat", "Comunicat");

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
 $Id_User = $_SESSION['IdUser'];

 $nome = $_POST['Nome'];

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
....
```

Comment: O meu é ligeiramente diferente, e é essa diferença que faz a diferença, nesse exemplo é apenas php, no meu tenho php e html

Comment: Alem do mais, os valores do exemplo são so 2 e fixos, os meus são dinamicos, vem de BD.

Comment: Exatamente, mas eu coloco $var = $_POST['Nome']; e diz me que a variavel não existe, por isso devo estar a colocar algo errado.

Comment: Bom, eu coloquei um comentario e apaguei, pois para mim duplicatas deveriam conter respostas aceitas. Segundo, tem ctz que o name deve ser colocado no formato de string? Na pergunta relacionada não está dessa forma.

Comment: Essas diferenças que disse não fazem a diferença. `$var = $_POST['Nome'];` tem de dar a opção escolhida.

Comment: Olá, como eu referi acima o "$var = $_POST['Nome'];" não funciona, diz que a variavel não existe.

Comment: @Sa tente mudar o `name` de `name="Nome"` para `name=Nome`. Não trabalho com `php`, mas na pergunta relacionada está nesse formato.

Comment: @SaPires coloque o código do arquivo `verificarMensagem.php`. O código do formulário está aparentemente correto.

Comment: @GustavoCinque O correto é delimitar os atributos, como por exemplo o `name`, entre aspas. E isso é HTML, não PHP =)

Comment: Você poderia postar o código onde está tentando recuperar o valor do `combobox`? o `combobox` está sendo populado corretamento com os dados do `BD`?

Comment: Tente explicar melhor qual é o problema. Está fazendo alguma coisa de errado, a forma de apanhar variáveis de um formulário é essa mesma. `$var = $_POST['oNamedaVariavel'];`. E não importa se tem HTML no meio ou se vem do banco a informação.

Comment: Já adicionei o verificaMensagem.php , a combobox é alimentada corretamente e são listados os valores